# How to make the content in the table align to the left?

Tags: tables, tabularx

I tend to forget Latex again.

How to make the content to start from left, while the first row remains middle?

[image]

Myt MWE:

```
  \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{table}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|C{8cm}|C{8cm}|}
        \hline 
        \bf{No.} & \bf{Revision} & \bf{Action Taken} \tabularnewline
        \hline
        1. & Testing Testing Testing & Action Taken Action Taken \tabularnewline
        \hline
        2. & Testing Testing Testing & Action Taken Action Taken  \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Comment: How or where is the `C` column type defined? Have you considered changing both instances of `C` to `p`?

Comment: Incidentally, you should *not* encase a `longtable` environment in a `center` environment. And please replace all instances of `\bf` with `\textbf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{longtable, makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalsize\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadgape{}


\begin{document}

\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.2}
    \begin{longtable}{|c|*{2}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}p{5cm}|}}% with 8cm columns table will  not fit on page
        \hline
        \thead{No.} & \thead{Revision} & \thead{Action Taken}   \tabularnewline
        \hline
        1. & Testing Testing Testing & Action Taken Action Taken \tabularnewline
        \hline
        2. & Testing Testing Testing & Action Taken Action Taken  \tabularnewline
        \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. However, the table is located at the centre. and not the left

Comment: @aan, table is horizontally centered, also column headers are horizontal centered in cells as you show in image in question, content in other rows are left aligned. If you like to have different alignment of text in tables, then please clarify this in your question.

Comment: @aan - `longtable` environments are automatically centered horizontally.